# Regex String Number bash

Tags: bash, regex, sed, awk

I have this situation:

```
$FILE_NAME = '207.Skyfall.2012.iTA-ENG.Bluray.1080p.x264.mkv'
echo $FILE_NAME | sed 's/.[0-9].*//' | sed 's/\./ /g'

Result empty the regex remove all
```

if the file doesn't start with numbers then everything works.

```
$FILE_NAME = 'Skyfall.2012.iTA-ENG.Bluray.1080p.x264.mkv'

Result: Skyfall
```

I need this to automatically extrapolate the name of the movie and remove everything else after the year

Can help to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, `.[0-9].*` matches any character then a digit then anything, so it matches the whole line and replace it with nothing.

In the second example, it doesn't match `Skyfall`, it matches the first dot and a digit (i.e. `2`) and averything after, so everything from a character before a digit upto end of line is replaced with nothing.

You should use:

```
s/\.[0-9]\+.*$//
```

this will remove the first dot followed by 1 or more digits and everything after with nothing.

Comment: echo 207.Skyfall.2012.iTA-ENG.Bluray.1080p.x264-CYBER.mkv | sed 's/\.[0-9]+.*$//' | sed 's/\./ /g'

but the result is :

207 Skyfall 2012 iTA-ENG Bluray 1080p x264 mkv

Comment: @michel: Sorry, escape the `+`, see my edit

Comment: ok now work. Thx

Comment: @michel: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
s/[0123456789.]*([^.]*).*/\1/
```

Example:

```
# echo $FILE_NAME | sed -E 's/[0123456789.]*([^.]*).*/\1/'
Skyfall
```

Comment: thx for help.

i need to have initial name : 007 Skyfall
the first help work :

s/\.[0-9]\+.*$//

and remove all after .2012